# React Native TextInput auto grow when multilne

Tags: react-native

I want to create a TextInput which can grow automatically when it has multilines.

```
 <TextInput
            placeholder="Type Comment"
            value={this.state.comment.value}
            onChangeText={value => this.onChangeComment(value)}
            onPress={() => this.uploadComment()}
            multiline={true}
            maxLength={200}
            numberOfLines={5}
          />
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Think that the React Native team fixed it in current version (0.59) with the `multiline` prop.

This works for me

```
  <TextInput
    style={{
      width: '90%',
      borderColor: 'gray',
      borderWidth: 1,
      padding: 2,
    }}
    multiline
    onChangeText={text => this.setState({ text })}
    value={this.state.text}
  />
```

Comment: How would one do this using functional components?

Comment: You do a 'const [text, setText] = React.useState' followed by 'const onChangeTextHandler = React.useCallback(text => setText(text),[setText])' and then you do the prop like 'onChangeText={onChangeTextHandler}'

Comment: And 'value={text}' for the last prop

Answer (score 11):

To implement auto grow multiline text input, you can adjust the height of the text input according to the content size in the textInput.

you can use [onContentSizeChange](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#oncontentsizechange) prop in TextInput and call a function to increase/decrease the height of input.

Here is the quick example code

```
export default class YourComponent extends Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      newValue: '',
      height: 40
    }
  }

  updateSize = (height) => {
    this.setState({
      height
    });
  }

  render () {
    const {newValue, height} = this.state;

    let newStyle = {
      height
    }

    return (
    <TextInput
      placeholder="Your Placeholder"
      onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({value})}
      style={[newStyle]}
      editable
      multiline
      value={value}
      onContentSizeChange={(e) => this.updateSize(e.nativeEvent.contentSize.height)}
    />
    )
  }

}
```

OR

You might want to use [react-native-auto-grow-textinput](https://github.com/rusfearuth/react-native-auto-grow-textinput)

Comment: I tried this solution, but onContentSizeChange fires on initial render and sets a different height for me. Don't understand why

Answer (score 7):

### With React Hooks

Just to add to Shivam's answer, here is the version with hooks:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export default function MyTextInput(props) {
    const [height, setHeight] = useState(42)
    return <TextInput
        style={styles.input, {height: height}}
        onContentSizeChange={e => setHeight(e.nativeEvent.contentSize.height)} />
}
```

Comment: Could you please look into this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74456363/alignitems-flex-end-not-working-with-oncontentsizechange

Answer (score 1):

Use module for this

```js
import {AutoGrowingTextInput} from 'react-native-autogrow-textinput';

return (
  <AutoGrowingTextInput 
    style={styles.textInput} 
    placeholder={'Your Message'}
    value={value}
  />
)
```

Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-autogrow-textinput

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else wondering how to have it grow AND shrink by new lines here's what I did.

```js
const [text,setText] = useState('');
const [textHeight,setTextHeight = useState(35);
    
<TextInput
   style={{height:textHeight,maxHeight:200}}
   value={text}
   multiline
   onChangeText={(e)=>{
      setText(e);
      setTextHeight(35 + (e.split('\n').length-1) * 20);
   }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `multiline` prop and then set a `minHeight` and `maxHeight` in the styles like so

```
<TextInput
    multiline
    style={{
        flex: 1,
        alignSelf: "flex-end",
        minHeight: 48,
        maxHeight: 100,
    }}
    placeholder="Type Your Message"
/>
```

Don't bother setting the `numberOfLines`