# Why does the TextInput's height change on first render?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, styled-components

I'm trying to build a custom autogrow text input in ReactNative.

Starting height should be `48`, but after it renders it sets the height to `53.71428680419922` and I don't understand why.

The code is here

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components/native'

const Input = styled.TextInput`
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 16;
  padding-bottom: 16;
  padding-top: 16;
  height: ${props => props.height};
  ${props => props.underline
    ? {
      paddingLeft: 0,
      paddingRight: 0,
      borderBottomWidth: 1,
    } : {
      marginTop: 18,
      paddingLeft: 22,
      paddingRight: 22,
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderStyle: 'solid',
    }}
`

export default class TextField extends Component {
  state = {
    height: 48,
  }

  handleContentSize = ({ nativeEvent: { contentSize: { height } } }) => {
    this.setState({ height })
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Input
          height={this.state.height}
          underline={underline}
          multiline={!underline}
          onContentSizeChange={this.handleContentSize}
        />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you examined the "DOM" to see what other css rules may be getting applied against it?

Comment: Not really. I followed @shivam's answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50061756/react-native-textinput-auto-grow-when-multilne.
I tried it with and without styled-components and I get the same thing