# alignItems = "flex-end" not working with onContentSizeChange

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox, react-native-stylesheet

I am trying to fix the corner icons to the bottom of the screen regardless the expansion of the text area. I tried with `position=absolute and bottom = 0` but it got hidden behind my `textArea`.

Here is what it looks like right now:

[image]

**This is what I want.**

[image]

I just need to fix send and add image icon to the bottom corners of the screen.
Please guide me how i can achieve that.

**Here my styleSheet** :

```
StyleSheet.create({
    containerStyle: {
      ...shadowStyle,
      minHeight: 72,
      width: "100%",
      paddingHorizontal: Spacing.m,
      alignItems: "flex-end",
      flexDirection: "row",
      padding: 10,
      borderTopLeftRadius: Spacing.s,
      borderTopRightRadius: Spacing.s,
      backgroundColor: colors.gray10,
    },
    textImageWrapper: {
      width: "79%",
      borderRadius: Radius.s,
      backgroundColor: colors.white,
    },
    inputStyleShort: {
      ...Typography.callout,
      flexWrap: "wrap",
      minHeight: 40,
      paddingLeft: Spacing.m,
      borderRadius: Radius.s,
      backgroundColor: colors.white,
    },
    inputStyle: {
      ...Typography.callout,
      flexWrap: "wrap",
      height: 40,
      borderRadius: Radius.s,
      paddingLeft: Spacing.m,
      paddingTop: 11,
    },
    submitButton: {
      backgroundColor: colors.green25,
      flexDirection: "row",
      justifyContent: "center",
      alignItems: "center",
      marginLeft: Spacing.s,
      width: 40,
      height: 40,
      borderRadius: Radius.s,
    },
    addImageButton: {
      width: "8%",
      height: Spacing.l,
      flexDirection: "row",
      alignItems: "center",
    },
```

**Here is my design code** :

```
 const calculateImageContainer = selectedImage.length ? { height: 280 } : { alignItems: "center" };
  return (
    <View style={[getStyle.containerStyle, calculateImageContainer]}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={getStyle.addImageButton}
        onPress={() => setImageSelectionVisible(true)}
      >
        {renderSvgIcon("addPicture", colors.gray90, null, null)}
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View style={getStyle.textImageWrapper}>
        <TextInput
          ref={inputRef}
          value={inputValue}
          style={inputValue.length ? getStyle.inputStyleShort : getStyle.inputStyle}
          placeholder={placeholder || i18n.t("community.writeComment")}
          placeholderTextColor="gray"
          multiline
          textAlignVertical="top"
          onChangeText={onChange}
          maxLength={maxLength || 500}
        />
        {selectedImage?.length ? (
          <ImagesLayout
            path="AvyCommentLinearInput"
            images={selectedImage}
            handleRemoveImagePress={removeImage}
          />
        ) : null}
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPressSubmit} style={getStyle.submitButton}>
        {renderSvgIcon("message_send_icon", colors.white, IconSize.m, IconSize.m)}
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <ImageSelectionMethod
        isVisible={isImageSelectionVisible}
        onClose={() => setImageSelectionVisible(false)}
        onCameraPicker={showCamera}
        onImagePicker={showPhotoGalleryPicker}
      />
    </View>
```

Comment: just add left at iamgeButton, and right at send button.``right: num``, ``left: num``

Answer (score 0):

I would try to add

`"flex: 1"` - to `containerStyle`

`"justifyContent: 'flex-end'"` - to `addImageButton` and `submitButton` styles.

You can check an example [here](https://snack.expo.dev/CLUyDplhz)

Answer (score 0):

simply add

> alignItems: 'end'

to  containerStyle

Comment: maybe alignItems: flex-end?

Comment: Yes,both work the same in this case @talent-jsdev

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
alignSelf : 'flex-end'
```

in `submitButton` and `addImageButton` styles

Answer (score 0):

You can add `zIndex={1}` where you have used `bottom={0}` and `position={"absolute"}`